# is it possible to upgrade to a new version via terminal?

Tags: upgrade, updates, 13.10

I've noticed on a acer travelmate 5720, that runs Ubuntu 13.04, it doesn't show or pickup the latest 13.10 version. I did check die update settings and it is set pickup/show the latest updates. But with the necessary settings set, it doesn't pickup the latest version. And it does have access to full free internet. Is there some solutions? Or can I update via terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. And it's the best way (for me at least).

check for new versions:

```
do-release-upgrade -c
```

and then:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

for more info:

```
man do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

First, just a minor nitpick about some ubuntu terminology:

update = fetching an up to date list of packages
upgrade = install a new version of a package or the whole system (release upgrade).

Hence if you say you cannot "see the latest updates", the reader might at first think you have troubles accessing the ubuntu mirrors. While in your case cannot perform a release upgrade to the latest.

By default only LTS (long term support) release upgrades are offered.

You can choose whether to allow you to install non LTS releases by changing a setting via the GUI (sorry I don't have an ubuntu GUI available right now, so I cannot help you find the correct place), or by editing this file:

```
/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Just ensure there is: `prompt=normal`

Then you can do perform the upgrade to 13.10 (either via the release upgrade gui or with `do-release-upgrade` as shown in devmind's answer)